# How to handle "Alexa" before Invocation

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm having issues where my Echo Dot is recognizing my Wake Word, "Alexa," in my full request before my Invocation.
ex. "alexa ask ..." as opposed to simply "ask ..."

This is causing my request to fail in the Alexa Developer Console.

I attempted to handle the issue in the setting I could find in the Alexa Developer Console, but I didn't have any luck finding anything.  If I type directly into the Alexa Simulator, I have the same results.  If I talk fast, my Echo Dot doesn't seem to include "alexa" at the beginning of the request.

What do I need to do to handle my Wake Word, "alexa," being recognized before the start of my invocation?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand correctly your problem, in the simulator you **don't have** to put the wake word **Alexa** to trigger the skill.

With the real device instead you have to say the wake word to trigger the skill (and Intents) but the wake word will **not** be part of the request.